# Can I run a node child process with node script from a buffer and not from another file?

Tags: node.js, express, child-process

Currently I am generating a node script in a string/buffer from a parent node script. I am then writing the generate script in a file and  executing that file in a child process. Finally I unlink the temp scriptfile.

Here is the simplified code:

```
fs.writeFileSync(scriptFile, program_code); 
script_output = child_process.execSync("node " + scriptFile).toString('utf8');
fs.unlinkSync(scriptFile);
```

Now that I have the output, I continue further processing. This works fine.

However, I feel that the overhead of writing to a temp file could be avoided if I can somehow run the node script from the in-memory buffer that I have rather than writing it to a file first.

I looked at  the [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module of node but did not find any way to do this. May be I missed something or is there some other way to do this?  I am looking for something like this:

```
 script_output = child_process.execSync("node " + ...).toString('utf8')
```

Perhaps some shell programming trick? I looked at the `-e` and the `-i` option to node and that did not cut it. I tried the `<<` here document shell feature with the -i option but the `<` prompt of the `REPL` mode appears to create a syntax issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into Node's [VM API](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html). I haven't actually tried this, but it looks like `vm.runInNewContext()` might do what you need without launching a new copy of Node.

Comment: will look into it. Upvoted. Sorry for not replying earlier.  Will marks as accepted answer after giving it a try.